# Create MongoDB database using the mongo command

Tags: mongodb

The MongoDB docs [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongo/#cmdoption-mongo-arg-db) say: `mongo STAR_WARS` connects to the `STAR_WARS` database. I was wondering if it is possible to pass in the name of a non-existing database you would to create in such command. I am specifically trying this command as my db is remote.

```
CMD=$(cat <<EOF
if (db.getUsers({ usersInfo: "${MONGO_USER}" }) == 0) {
  db.createUser({
    user: "${MONGO_USER}",
    pwd: "${MONGO_PASSWORD}",
    roles: [{ role: "dbAdmin", db: "admin" }, "readWrite"],
    passwordDigestor : "server"
  });
}
EOF
)
mongo ${MONGO_ROOT_DSN} NEW_DB_NAME --eval "${CMD}"
```

`MONGO_ROOT_DSN` is of format `mongodb://root:ROOT_PASSWORD@HOST:PORT/?authSource=admin`
The passed in `CMD` is there to add an additional user to the database.

With this command, I get the following error:

```
MongoDB shell version v3.4.4
connecting to: mongodb://root:ROOT_PASSWORD@HOST:PORT/?authSource=admin
MongoDB server version: 3.6.12
WARNING: shell and server versions do not match
2020-01-26T09:10:59.003+0000 E -        [main] file [NEW_DB_NAME] doesn't exist
failed to load: NEW_DB_NAME
```

Is this method possible or do I have to connect the shell and use the `use NEW_DB_NAME;` command? I believe you can't have the `use` command in non-interactive (e.g. running a script in a Docker container). Therefore, one needs to be able to pass in the name of the db to be created.

Is the warning causing this issue or is it related to the db address format?

Why is this NEW_DB_NAME interpreted as a file name? A file name for what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the mongodb docs, you are able to select another database with:

```
mongo mongodb://root:ROOT_PASSWORD@HOST:PORT/NEW_DB_NAME --eval "${CMD}"
```

> This syntax is the only way to connect to a specific database. (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongo/#cmdoption-mongo-arg-db)

Otherwise you will get a file not found error because it will try to execute a JavaScript file. (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/#execute-a-javascript-file)

Besides the connection string, why do you want to connect to another database when the information in the roles options points to the 'admin' database?

```
roles: [{ role: "dbAdmin", db: "admin" }, "readWrite"]
```

What do you think of using 'db.getSiblingDB("NEW_DB_NAME")' within your JavaScript function, as an alternative?

> You can use db.getSiblingDB() as an alternative to the use  helper. This is particularly useful when writing scripts using the mongo shell where the use helper is not available. (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.getSiblingDB/)

Comment: Thanks man! `db.getSiblingDB` came in really handy! As for your question, whether `admin` or `NEW_DB_NAME `, the new mongo user will have access to the new db (I tested). I'm not sure what the difference is though.